# How to remove attachment icon on jsqmessagesviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

By default its like this without any customization, its not me who add the icon

**Here is what I got:**
[image: What i got]

**What I'm looking for:**
[image]

Comment: The images are helpful, but an expert might want to know how you are using the jsqmessagesviewcontroller in code

Comment: By default its like this without any customization, its not me who add the icon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your  `viewDidLoad`,

simply do:

```
 self.inputToolbar.contentView.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
```

This is helpful...:)

Comment: @Patrick of course because any one who use this library have to do that to remove it.

Comment: @Gilber Maybe you can search a little: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/338 or https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/280

Comment: @Patrick totally agree as you might have said i m the one  who give the answer, and i cant accept it since your down vote totally wreck the little points i had.

Answer (score 3):

Got it, here is the answer :

```
self.inputToolbar.contentView.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
```